# Could not set unknown property 'localProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

Hello After upgrading Android studio to `3.3.2` , I get this error every time I run the app:

```
Could not set unknown property 'localProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
testInstrumentationRunnerdef localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by calling `flutter create .` to re-create Android files which resulted in successful building.