# Could not get unknown property 'localProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

same question is also asked here but doesn't solve the problem that's why it is asked here again. [Could not set unknown property 'localProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003992/could-not-set-unknown-property-localproperties-for-project-app-of-type-org)

i'm running **flutter build appbundle** command and getting below error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'D:\LiveApps\himachal_quiz\android\app\build.gradle' line: 7
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > Could not get unknown property 'localProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.

**Code in app/build.gradle**:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

**it says error in line no. 7 see the images for line number 7 for the above code.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if your path to flutter.sdk in local.properties matches with your sdk path in Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter. Also check if your path to flutter sdk is correct.

local.properties file is available in android folder.

Refer images below:

[flutter sdk path in Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q47vh.png)

[flutter sdk path in local.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11xDy.png)

Comment: SDK path is correct on both places. as the error is asking for 'localProperties'. I added the code LocalProperties code back which was replaced by the above code. 

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

is it correct to keep both the code because in app release doc this code needs to replace with the above code. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle

Comment: Yes, you can keep both, local.properties file and key.properties file. In the documentation, it says you have to add the keystore information(step 1), not replace it.

Comment: Yes i read that... After this solution i got this error while building aapbundle

e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (19, 22): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (23, 40): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (25, 40): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (27, 52): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (39, 55): Unresolved reference: R

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.

Comment: Have you tried solutions from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621301/android-studio-3-1-3-unresolved-reference-r-kotlin

Comment: Yes this work for me. i wrote the whole solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020174/flutter-error-listtilenativeadfactory-kt-19-22-unresolved-reference-r/75020175