# Flutter error: ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (19, 22): Unresolved reference: R

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (19, 22): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (23, 40): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (25, 40): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (27, 52): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (39, 55): Unresolved reference: R
e: ...\ListTileNativeAdFactory.kt: (43, 51): Unresolved reference: R

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.
```

I got this error while i was building **appbundle** for release.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the default package name like this: `com.example.your_app`

**CTRL+Click on the error** the file will open:
match the **package name** here if you have changed it. on the top

e.g. `package com.helloNetwork.abc_app`

Now for **Unresolved reference: R**

```
import com.helloNetwork.abc_app.R
```

This is how i solved this and got the appbundle in output.